# Windows 7 Explorer Has No View > Explorer Bar > Folders Command?

Tags: windows-7

What is the alternative to the old **View > Explorer Bar > Folders** command in Windows 7 (Aero View)? Is my interactive experience improved because of my inability to show/hide folder trees (especially with a keyboard shortcut) in Windows 7?

Comment: This belongs in SuperUser

Answer (score 3):

Organize | Layout | Navigation Pane.